# cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch

Tags: hadoop, rpc

I have this exception when I tried to invoke a remote method,

```
2013-01-28 16:46:09,911 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:training (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch: Protocol org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol version mismatch. (client = 69, server = 1)
2013-01-28 16:46:09,912 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 8020, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.getFileInfo from 192.168.140.1:55126: error: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch: Protocol org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol version mismatch. (client = 69, server = 1)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch: Protocol org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol version mismatch. (client = 69, server = 1)
```

I am using Cloudera CDH4 vm (Version 2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2)

How could the ClientProtocol on the server side has a version of "1"?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the client and the server from the same package ? Also make sure the classpaths are correct .

Comment: No, I am writing my own client.

Comment: By client , I didnt mean the client program that you wrote . I meant the DFSClient jar you use .